# Why ADecimalNumber.ToString("#,##0") round the number?

Tags: c#, string

C#: I have a decimal number, I want to separate the thousand numbers by a comma but not round the number. As answers of stack overflow, I used `.ToString("#,##0")` but it rounds the number. It's not acceptable for me to round the number!

In my model I have:
 `public decimal? ADecimalNumber { get; set; }`
In Controller I have:
 `ViewBag.ADecimalNumber = result?.ADecimalNumber;`
And in View I have:
 `@(ViewBag.ADecimalNumber != null ? ViewBag.ADecimalNumber.ToString("#,##0") : '-')`

The ViewBag value is `11106.8314M` in quick-watch mode, and the `ViewBag.ADecimalNumber.ToString("#,##0")` result is `"11,107"`.

Comment: Well what value did you expect? You're basically saying that you don't want any decimal places... perhaps you want to add `.#####` or similar to the end of your format string? (As many decimal places as you want.) Or just use a standard format string instead that includes thousand separators?

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC - you could (and) should demonstrate this in a [mcve] as a console app.

Comment: Well, because truncating is the special case; rounding is the default case. When you have special needs, you need to use special code to achieve them.

Comment: You are asking it to format it without decimal places so it rounds it. In this case, it is rounded up.
Im guessing you are expecting 4 decimal place so you would have to add #,###.####

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rounding is part of the behavior of the `#` custom digit formatter. Use `Math.Truncate()` to cut off the digits after the period if you do not want rounding:

```
Math.Truncate(ViewBag.ADecimalNumber).ToString("#,##0")
```

If you want to print n decimal places though, multiply the number with the nth-power of 10, truncate, then divide by that same power, for example: `Math.Truncate(123456.78M * 10M)/10M` will give 123456.7 which you could print using the format string `#,###.#`

Answer (score 2):

It's default behavior of custom specifier. See [The "#" Custom Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--custom-specifier).

> The "##" format string causes the value to be rounded to the nearest digit preceding the decimal, where rounding away from zero is always used. For example, formatting 34.5 with "##" would result in the value 35.